# is it possible to add sound effect to the Kinect Paint buttons?

Tags: paint, kinect, soundplayer

sorry for my bad English and straight forwarding.

i have something about the coding to ask...

i would like to ask, is it possible to add sound for all the button?

seems like the button with a "click" sound when it is selected would be nice.

anyone have any idea to do it?

is it add the .wav file source in somewhere here?

```
    new BrushSelection(
        new Uri("/KinectPaint;component/Resources/pen-unselected.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), 
        new Uri("/KinectPaint;component/Resources/pen-selected.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), 
        KinectPaintbrush.Marker, 
        "pen"),
```

or

```
SoundPlayer ClickSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Media\ClickSound.wav");
    ClickSound.Play();
```

Comment: Ok, if I'm correct you have to have some onclick action or something like this. So can't you just play the sound in this onclick action ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this code to work, once you defined the `PlaySound` Method, go to select all of the buttons on the wpf and chose the `EventHandler` Setting under propertys, and add the `PlaySound` method to the `CLick` event, and obviously `startSoundPlayer` is going to be whatever you want to call your sound player. Oh and this is using Wpf

```
 namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    System.Media.SoundPlayer startSoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav");



    private void PlaySound(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        startSoundPlayer.Play();
    }
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

You can have an event handler for the button in which it will trigger the sound clip to be played.